# Prevent horizontal scroll and keep vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag where I WANT vertical scrolling and DO NOT WANT horizontal scrolling. I have searched a lot, but couldn't find the solution to prevent horizontal scroll and keep vertical scroll for a PARTICULAR div tag.

```
 <div style="max-width:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
```

`overflow-x:hidden` doesn't work, as it just hides the scrollbar but doesn't disable it. Please help.

Comment: Kk, did not see that, so wich browser do you use ? You want your div to take all the available space on X but hide on Y right?

Comment: I don't really understand that last bit. overflow-x:hidden works perfectly for me; it completely prevents me from scrolling horizontally, even if the content overflows. What exactly do you mean by "hidden, but not disabled"?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see *exactly* what you're trying to do. Is your `div` somewhere within the rest of the page? Is it the whole page you're trying to stop scrolling horizontally? Please could you elaborate a little further in your post. Could you post a little more of your code, too, as this might help us to recreate the problem you're having? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some good tips on asking a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example :)

Comment: yes my div is to the left of the page; overflow-x:hidden doesn't work

Comment: I edited my answer again, just take a look.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED AGAIN

That's my last try:

`word-wrap: break-word;`

If you text is overflowing on X it should just break it to a new line.

Comment: Doesn't. I said it doesn't work. It just HIDES the scrollbar doesn't disable it

Comment: Hum, wich browser do you use?

Comment: google chrome. It is not working. I have tried a lot.

Comment: (I'am definitively blind... sorry, i just want to help you...) If that don't work too.... :/

Comment: @PrasitaMukherjee - What the hack is the difference between a hidden and a disabled scrollbar here? In your question you're saying, that you don't want horizontal scrolling, so hiding the scrollbar is a solution!

Comment: overflow-x:hidden simply 'hides' the scrollbar , but it still scrolls, if width exceeds horizontally as overflow-y:auto is there . Only if I do overflow:hidden, it stops scrolling. But that disables the vertical scrollbar too. overflow-y:auto is enabling both horizontal and vertical scrollbar; combining it with overflow-x:hidden is not disabling horizontal scroll, simply hiding it.

Comment: Okay, did you tryed word-wrap? (Edited my answer again) @linusg he want to show the text on X.